# How to delete a group of values when a certain certain condition is met?

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

Orginally the data look like this:

```
obs gr  x1  x2  gender
1   1   0   4   M
2   1   4   13  M
3   1   13  15  M
4   1   15  15  M
5   2   0   1   F
6   2   1   15  F
7   2   15  19  F
8   2   19  30  F
9   2   30  31  F
10  3   0   2   F
11  3   2   4   F
12  3   4   7   F
13  4   0   1   M
14  4   1   14  M
15  4   14  22  M
16  4   22  31  M
17  4   31  31  M
18  4   31  60  M
19  4   60  60  M
```

I would like to make the data look like this: within each group ("gr"), if values of x1 and x2 are equal in any row, all the values in that group will be deleted. So the new data should look like this:

```
obs gr  x1  x2  gender
1   1   0   1   F
2   1   1   15  F
3   1   15  19  F
4   1   19  30  F
5   1   30  31  F
6   2   0   2   F
7   2   2   4   F
8   2   4   7   F
```

And numbers in the column "gr" should be rearranged as well. That is, `2` in `gr` becomes `1`, and `3` in `gr` becomes `2` in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Seeing your expected outcome, I am confused. For instance, obs 4 has 15 in x1 and x2. If I am not mistaken, you do not want any data from the group, gr1. Is that right? The other thing is that the expected outcome seems not to match with the original data. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, jazzurro. The expected outcome does not contain any values for group 1 and group 4 from the original data, as within either group, there is at least one row that has the same value for x1 and x2. Although the two data sets do not match (and the group numbers are changed), the expected outcome is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way. I am sure there will better ways. First, I grouped the data by `gr`. Second, I checked if there is any row which has identical values in `x1` and `x2`. If there is such a row, I asked R to assign `1`, otherwise `0`. Finally, I used `filter` to do the subset. After that, I did some work to change `gr` as you requested.

```
group_by(mydf, gr) %>%
mutate(check = ifelse(any(x1 == x2) == TRUE, 1, 0)) %>%
filter(check == 0) %>%
ungroup %>%
mutate(gr = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(gr) != 0))) %>%
select(-check)

#  obs gr x1 x2 gender
#1   5  1  0  1      F
#2   6  1  1 15      F
#3   7  1 15 19      F
#4   8  1 19 30      F
#5   9  1 30 31      F
#6  10  2  0  2      F
#7  11  2  2  4      F
#8  12  2  4  7      F
```

UPDATE

Thanks to akrun's kind advice, I learned a concise way to handle this case.

```
group_by(mydf, gr) %>%
filter(!any(x1 == x2)) %>%
ungroup %>%
mutate(obs = 1:n(),
       gr = as.numeric(factor(gr)))

#  obs gr x1 x2 gender
#1   1  1  0  1      F
#2   2  1  1 15      F
#3   3  1 15 19      F
#4   4  1 19 30      F
#5   5  1 30 31      F
#6   6  2  0  2      F
#7   7  2  2  4      F
#8   8  2  4  7      F
```

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(obs = 1:19, gr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), x1 = c(0L, 4L, 
13L, 15L, 0L, 1L, 15L, 19L, 30L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 14L, 22L, 
31L, 31L, 60L), x2 = c(4L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 15L, 19L, 30L, 
31L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 14L, 22L, 31L, 31L, 60L, 60L), gender = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("obs", 
"gr", "x1", "x2", "gender"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Comment: Hi, jazzurro: Your code works. It is fantastic. I really appreciate your help. Actually, before I asked this question, I tried "subset, "with", "%in%", etc, and they did not do well for me. I need to spend more time learning the package "dplyr". Thanks again.

Comment: @Jason You are welcome. I am glad that the code is working for you. :)

Comment: @akrun Yeah I was thinking about that now after seeing your answer. I am still having some troubles to use `filter` in efficient ways. Thank you very much for the advice. I will revise my answer.

Comment: @akrun yes, I have seen a post related to `ifelse`. I try to avoid `ifelse` as much as I can. In this case, your way is the concise way. I thought there would be better ways, but I could not come up with ideas like yours when I was solving the question.

Comment: @jazzurro Your code was already good, just needed some modifications.

Comment: @akrun That modification will make a huge difference when you deal with huge data. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)# data.table_1.9.5
setDT(mydf)[,.SD[!any(x1==x2)] , gr][, 
            c('gr', 'obs') := list(rleid(gr), 1:.N)][]
#    gr obs x1 x2 gender
#1:  1   1  0  1      F
#2:  1   2  1 15      F
#3:  1   3 15 19      F
#4:  1   4 19 30      F
#5:  1   5 30 31      F
#6:  2   6  0  2      F
#7:  2   7  2  4      F
#8:  2   8  4  7      F
```

Note: `.SD` could be replaced with `.I` to get the row index and then use it for subsetting.

Or using `base R`

```
transform(mydf[with(mydf, !ave(x1==x2, gr, FUN=any)),], 
          obs=seq_along(obs), gr=as.numeric(factor(gr)))
```